# redirect outgoing dns queries to localhost using iptables

Tags: domain-name-system, iptables, tcp, dnat, unbound

**Problem**

There are some outgoing **TCP** DNS requests in my Ubuntu server that I couldn't control them to be resolved by Unbound on 127.0.0.1:53 which uses 208.67.222.222 to resolve everything, and I see those TCP DNS packets finally going from my public IP address to famous DNS servers such as 8.8.8.8 and 1.1.1.1.

**What I have done**

```
ipset -N myipset iphash
ipset -A myipset 127.0.0.1
ipset -A myipset 208.67.222.222

iptables -t nat -D OUTPUT -m udp -p udp --dport 53 -m set ! --match-set myipset -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:53
iptables -t nat -D OUTPUT -m tcp -p tcp --dport 53 -m set ! --match-set myipset -j DNAT --to 127.0.0.1:53
```

I used OUTPUT because I believe PREROUTING doesn't affect them as they are locally-generated and to redirect them before they are sent out. But when I run these commands DNS for those TCP packets simply doesn't work, but `dnslookup -vc` using Unbound works.

**My question**

Should I do something special for these rules to work? Did I miss something? Maybe some more sysctl.conf stuff?

**/etc/sysctl.conf**

```
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
net.ipv4.conf.all.route_localnet = 1
net.ipv4.conf.ens3.route_localnet = 1
```

**/etc/unbound/unbound.conf**

```
server:
  port: 53
  cache-min-ttl: 600
  rrset-cache-size: 64m
  msg-cache-size: 32m
  prefetch: yes
  serve-expired: yes
  serve-expired-ttl: 86400
  do-not-query-localhost: no
  tcp-upstream: yes
  outgoing-num-tcp: 2000
  incoming-num-tcp: 2000

remote-control:
  control-enable: yes

forward-zone:
  name: "."
  forward-addr: 208.67.222.222
```

Unbound is running on both TCP and UDP ports 53.

Answer (score 0):

A noobish mistake. `iptables` rules were Ok. The problem was with `unbound`'s config (actually me not knowing how it works!), I had to add `access-control` too, so it accepts TCP requests from my server's public IP address:

```
server:
  ...
  access-control: <server public ip address>/24 allow_snoop
```

and then restarted `unbound`. So far seems good.